# What is the right height for login with Google button?

Tags: angular-material, material-design, google-signin

According to examples in [Google Sign-In Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) the height of the login button has to be 46px, but the height of the button component in the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview) is 36px (So I suppose it is correct button height in Material design overall).

So, what is the correct size for login with google button in my site on material design?

Answer (score 0):

The sign-in guidelines are not Material Design, but they allow for changing the button according to the application design (*emphasis* mine):

> **Matching your own app's style**
>
> Using the standard Google Sign-In button is strongly recommended as it enables Google users to more
> quickly identify the Google option. *If you need to to adapt the button
> to match your app design* or translate the text "Sign in with" or "Sign
> in", follow these guidelines.
>
> ***Size***
>
> *You can scale the button as needed* for different devices and
> screen sizes, but you must preserve the aspect ratio so that the
> Google logo is not stretched.